# Huffman,Stack overflow

Tags: c++

```
void decodeFile(ibstream& infile, Node* encodingTree, ostream& file) {
    // initializing map here.

    string code = "";
    /*while (true) {
        code += integerToString(infile.readBit());        
        if (map.containsKey(code)) {
            if (map[code] == PSEUDO_EOF) break;
            file.put(map[code]);
            code = "";
        }
    }*/
    bitToString(infile,file,code,map);
}
```

given method with commented part works fine, I'm tring to do recursion instead of while cycle.

```
void bitToString(ibstream& infile, ostream& file,string& code,Map<string,ext_char>& map){      
    code += integerToString(infile.readBit());
    if (map.containsKey(code)) {
        if (map[code] == PSEUDO_EOF) return;
        file.put(map[code]);
        code="";
    }
    bitToString(infile,file,code,map);
}
```

but, with this recursion it gives stack owerflow error on big files.

> Unhandled exception at 0x621dffde in Huffman Encoding.exe: 0xC00000FD:
>   Stack overflow.

Comment: There are no branch to determine whether to continue the recursion or not, so it will do infinite recursion.

Comment: Turn your recursion into a loop. There's a natural limit on the depth of recursion - recursing for every bit of input would certainly exceed this limit. The recursion doesn't even serve any particular purpose in your code.

Comment: if (map[code] == PSEUDO_EOF) return; 
at the end of the encoded text there's PSEUFO_EOF char, that stops recursion.

Comment: so, Igor it's better to have th code in while loop?

Comment: `while` loop, or `for(;;)` loop, whatever you think is more convenient. Just not recursion.

Comment: ok, I'll do. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limit of function nesting. If you try for ex. nest function in function 10000 times you will get error. You can use recursion to do Huffman decoding but you need to combine it with iteration (or second recursion). You probably should reset your recursion after finding correct code and iterate to next code until EOF.